# Default spinner style in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-widget

I am developing an android application in which I am populating a spinner from database using simpleAdaptor.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter deptype =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.dbspinner, depcur, from, to);   dep.setAdapter(deptype);
```

Data is loading fine but I don't like the "Look" of the Spinner.

The spinner I got with

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> practype = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.practice, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

is more beautiful with a radio button on the side,while the one I got is just showing contents separated by lines which is not at all beautiful.

I tried various changes in my layout of dbspinner but nothing is equal to the default stock spinner in android. I also tried to replace dbspinner with android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item but I got blank boxes with radio buttons but no text.

How can I get the stock default spinner?

Should i load the contents of database into a string and give to array adapter? If so how to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple_spinner_item is defined as:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

So to use it as your item's view, use "text1" as your id in the resource integer array.

Ie:

```
// Create the array containing column names
String[] columns = new String[] { "ColumnNameX" };

// Create the array containing resource ids
int[] resources = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

// Create the cursor adapter
mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    MyActivity.this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    data,
    columns,
    resources);
```

Comment: No use :( still showing tiny boxes with a line between :(. How to load database column into a String? If I can do that I can directly use array adapter

Comment: It works - I'm using it. Make sure you're database is actually populated and you're using the right column name.

Comment: It is giving an error near android:id="@android:id/text1". I created a xml file and deleted everything and pasted this. Is that correct?

Comment: Error is No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/tvspin')

Comment: You need a better understanding of ID's and packages.

Don't use a different XML layout, use simple_spinner_item and use the code I provided. It assumes the TextView resource ID is "android.R.id.text1".

Comment: Hi I am able to get my mistake but still the same problem. Here is my code                                     '//Cursor Cursor depcur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM dept_masterdata WHERE "+hsname+"=1",null); startManagingCursor(depcur); String[] from = new String[]{"department"}; int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }; // Now creating an array adapter and set it to display using my row //Department SimpleCursorAdapter deptype =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, depcur, from, to); dep.setAdapter(deptype);'

Comment: Hi. I got it. Thanks a lot. I forgot to add this line deptype.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Comment: Hi, is it possible to change the color of the text in the spinner?

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code:

```
  AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Category");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(CATEGORIES_TXT, mSelectedCategory, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //new category selected
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

`CATEGORIES_TXT` is a String[] and `mSelectedCategory` an `int` representing the selected category.